# autodesk forge viewer.js update from 6.6 to 7.1 findPropertyDbPath return null

Tags: autodesk-forge

According to Document   
https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/viewer-release-notes-v-70 
Document.getPropertyDbPath - Use Document.getFullPath(Document.getRoot().findPropertyDbPath())

In 7.1 
i always get null when Document.getRoot().findPropertyDbPath() and Document.getFullPath(Document.getRoot().findPropertyDbPath()).

In 6.6
Document.getPropertyDbPath will return full address.

ps. i use viewer.loadModel to load model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The property db path is specific to a certain view so you will need to drill down to child node to get the path rather than `docRoot`:

```
const 3dViews = doc.getRoot().search({
                'type': 'geometry',
                'role': '3d'
});

3dviews[0].findPropertyDbPath() // get the db path of the first/default view
```

Comment: This should really be in the documentation.